# How to install TWRP on Huawei Honor 8 FRD-L14?

Tags: rooting, twrp, 7.0-nougat, huawei

I have tried rooting my FRD-L14 yesterday. I have successfully unlocked the bootloader, OEM, FRP, and developer mode on the phone to install TWRP. I have also installed ADB (with corresponding drivers like fastboot like the usual). I have inputted the usual flashing command through fastboot:

```
.\fastboot.exe flash recovery .\twrp-{version_name}-frd.img
```

However, after trying to flash both TWRP versions 3.6.2 & 3.0.2-0 ([as shown in a video guide to install TWRP on FRD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fTdGpYNOKzQ)), I am always stuck on the **"Your device is booting now..."** screen when entering recovery mode either through ADB or **[power] + [Vol Down]** buttons. I have to always press down **[power] + [Vol Up]** buttons in order to do a regular boot. I have already spent countless hours trying to look for a solution to install TWRP rather than giving up.

Some of the websites that I have browsed through seems to have a custom TWRP that is fit for FRD-L14 but unfortunately, the download links seem to have expired already.

[XDA Developer Link with no solutions on continuing to install TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/solved-stuck-on-your-device-is-booting-now.3650016/)

[Expired Custom TWRP Link Page](https://www.modaco.com/topic/377647-twrp-recovery-3020-for-honor-8/)

[Link where I get my official TWRP downloads](https://twrp.me/)

My phone is a FRD-L14C567B402 (USA only) running on Android 7.0 Nougat with Hisilicon Kirin 950 processers and EMUI version 5.0.4....

Current Plans:
I am planning to download every single TWRP version on the Official TWRP website for FRD and try every single one of them... If this fails, I am not sure how to successfully install TWRP

Any other suggestions or solutions to solving this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend to start with reading error message from fastboot flash recovery ;)

Comment: I am not sure how to enable error message while flashing the .img to the recovery through fastboot since I did not get any error messages while doing that!